# Reporting Youtube videos endpoint returning duration "P0D" for some items

Tags: youtube-api, youtube-data-api

P0D would be 0:00:00 duration and is obviously wrong.

Some example video ids that give this result are "D4MdHQOILdw", "IvuwTft-0cM", "WsDyRAPFBC8".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Figured out what was going on:

Youtube data api returns P0D for ongoing current live streams probably because there isn't a duration for them yet.